# Cannot run UglifyJS on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nodejs, javascript

I installed UglifyJS on Ubuntu 18.04 using:

```sh
sudo apt install node-uglify
```

And then I tried to run `uglifyjs` command, but got error messages:

```sh
$ uglifyjs -h
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'yargs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs:8:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I checked whether the `node-yargs` package is installed, and it was on my system.

My Node version is 10.18.1, how to I use UglifyJS on my Ubuntu?